# How i can get the number of followers from a Instagram profile using ASPX.NET (C#)

Tags: instagram

Im using the C# language in a ASP.NET project but i dont know how to do this. It is possible?

I already have the access code.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does appear to be possible to get the number of followers for an Instagram profile.

If you [query](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/) the Instagram api it returns the number of followers. You can [serialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179(v=vs.110).aspx) that data into an object to use the data in your application.

For example, `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/1574083/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN` will return the following data about the user.

```
{
"data": {
    "id": "1574083",
    "username": "snoopdogg",
    "full_name": "Snoop Dogg",
    "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_1574083_75sq_1295469061.jpg",
    "bio": "This is my bio",
    "website": "http://snoopdogg.com",
    "counts": {
        "media": 1320,
        "follows": 420,
        "followed_by": 3410
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find their API at [this address](http://instagram.com/developer/)
In the API console, it will generate you the URL according to what you need. It is really easy to use. According to the console, you have to access

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/followed-by

where `{user-id}` is the ID of your user.

It will probably return a list. Count them, and there you are!